# Describing the range of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a problem that asks for all the real number vectors $b_1$,$b_2$ such that

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 1\\
        12 & 3\\
        \end{pmatrix} * 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        \end{pmatrix} =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        b_1\\
        b_2\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

So far, I have reduced the matrix to
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 1 & b_1 \\
        0 & 0 & -3b_1 + b_2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

How do I solve from here?

Thank you all!

Comment: Hint: what do the equations your last matrix is representing tell you about the last row? What about how $b_1$ and $b_2$ are related?

Comment: $-3b_1 + b_2$ must equal zero.

Comment: So is there some relationship between $b_1$ and $b_2$ that you could use to simplify your matrix?

Comment: For the equation to be consistent, the last row of the reduced matrix must be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
4&1&b_1\\
0&0&-3b_1+b_2
\end{bmatrix} $$
This *really* encodes the system of equations
$$ 4x+y=b_1$$
$$ 0=-3b_1+b_2.$$
It's easy to see, then, that $3b_1=b_2$. So, we have that $b_1=\frac{1}{3}b_2.$ Thus, we have that $4x+y=b_1$, and so the solution set for this matrix equation is the line $y=-4x+b_1$. With these data, we can see that the range is of the set of vectors of the form 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
b_1\\
3b_1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: My professor has the answer as $
        \begin{matrix}
        b_1 \\
        3b_1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$  What does this mean?

Comment: Based on our relation $3b_1=b_2$, we can see that anything in the range must be of the form $(b_1,3b_1)$. Perhaps I should add this to the answer.